# SQL count and group by date and type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I have a quality system table. There are 2 types of quality points NCR and RMA.
RMA is external and NCR is internal. We log transactions to the table either as a NCR or a RMA. I would like to have a query that will count all of the RMA's and all of the NCR's then group them by monthly count. For example:

```
      MONTH          RMA          NCR
      JANUARY        10           54
      FEBRUARY       48           22
      MARCH          25           55
```

If the value is zero for the month or the month has not yet come up, I don't want to see it on the report.
the table. this is what I have.

```
SELECT MONTH(QualityControl.CreateDate) MONTH, COUNT(*) AS 'NCR'
FROM QualityControl
WHERE YEAR(QualityControl.CreateDate)=2015
and
QualityControl.NCR is not null 
GROUP BY MONTH(QualityControl.CreateDate)
```

This only gives me the month number (1=January) and the NCR count for that month.

Then I tried the following:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,CreateDate) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'January',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,CreateDate) WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'February',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,CreateDate) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'March',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,CreateDate) WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'April',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,CreateDate) WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'May',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,CreateDate) WHEN 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'June',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,CreateDate) WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'July',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,CreateDate) WHEN 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'August',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,CreateDate) WHEN 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'September',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,CreateDate) WHEN 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'October',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,CreateDate) WHEN 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'November',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,CreateDate) WHEN 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'December',
  SUM(CASE datepart(year,CreateDate) WHEN 2015 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTAL'
FROM
    QualityControl
WHERE
  CreateDate BETWEEN '2015/01/01' AND '2015/12/30'
```

And it gave me the count for NCR and RMA

Comment: Downvote because question is tagget with both "mysql" and "sql-server-2008". Which one is it?

Comment: In ANSI SQL single quotes are for string literals. Use double quotes for identifiers, e.g the column alias "January".

Comment: @Dan . . . Stack Overflow often suggests the MySQL tag for anything that looks like a question about SQL.  Newbies are probably inclined to say yes to suggested tags.  You probably shouldn't downvote them for that (it would be a different matter for someone with a rep in the hundreds or thousands).

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Noted, thanks. Removed my downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go with your first attempt, which is one row per value.  You want to count the valid "NCR" and "RMA" values.  You can use a `COUNT()` like this:

```
SELECT MONTH(qc.CreateDate) as MON, COUNT(NCR) as NCR, COUNT(RMA) as RMA
FROM QualityControl qc
WHERE CreateDate >= '2015-01-01' AND CreateDate < '2016-01-01' 
GROUP BY MONTH(qc.CreateDate)
ORDER BY MON;
```

With a column (or other expression), `COUNT()` counts the number of non-NULL values.  That seems to be exactly what you want.

If you wanted the `SUM()` of the values, then you would use `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`.

Note about the dates:

- The version using comparisons is better than the one using `YEAR()`, because it can make use of indexes.
- I changed the `BETWEEN` to `>=` and `<`.  This version works correctly, if your date/time column has a time component.  It also works for dates.
- December has 31 days.

Answer (score 0):

in sql server you can do all of these :

```
SELECT 
CASE datepart(month,getdate()) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS January,
CASE datepart(month,getdate()) WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "February",
CASE datepart(month,getdate()) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [March]
```

the best method would be
    SELECT datename(month, getdate())